# SQL ajuda a unir 2 selects

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

tenho 2 selects abaixo, como posso unir em apenas 1 select?

Eu preciso pegar tudo que vendeu num determinado período (BETWEEN) por item só que ao mesmo tempo eu tenho que pegar o que tinha de estoque do item até a data inicial.

para separar se é entrada ou saída é a opção d.tipo

Exemplo:

```
Produto     Estoque             qtd vendida
XPTO         100                     50
```

Select 1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.cat_id prod, p.id, p.nome id_prod, 
SUM( d.qtd ) AS qtd_prod, SUM( d.valor_total ) AS total_prod 
FROM lc_controle c 
INNER JOIN lc_detalhe d ON d.controle_id = c.id 
INNER JOIN `lc_cat` p ON p.id = d.cat_id 
WHERE d.tipo = '0' 
and c.dtConcat BETWEEN '$dtinicial' AND '$dtfinal' 
and c.exportado = 'Sim' 
GROUP BY d.cat_id 
ORDER BY qtd_prod DESC
```

Select 2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.cat_id prod, p.id, p.nome id_prod, 
SUM( d.qtd ) AS qtd_estoque
FROM lc_controle c 
INNER JOIN lc_detalhe d ON d.controle_id = c.id 
INNER JOIN `lc_cat` p ON p.id = d.cat_id 
WHERE d.tipo = '0' 
and c.dtConcat < '$dtinicial' 
and c.exportado = 'Sim' 
GROUP BY d.cat_id 
ORDER BY qtd_estoque DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Penso que dessa forma irá conseguir ter os resultados que pretende:

```
SELECT      DISTINCT TMP.*
FROM        (
                SELECT      DISTINCT d.cat_id   AS prod
                        ,   p.id
                        ,   p.nome              AS id_prod
                        ,   SUM(d.qtd)          AS qtd_prod
                        ,   SUM(d.valor_total)  AS total_prod
                        ,   SUM(0)              AS qtd_estoque
                FROM        lc_controle c 
                INNER JOIN  lc_detalhe  d ON d.controle_id  = c.id 
                INNER JOIN  lc_cat      p ON p.id           = d.cat_id 
                WHERE       d.tipo      = '0' 
                        AND c.dtConcat  BETWEEN '$dtinicial' AND '$dtfinal' 
                        AND c.exportado = 'Sim' 
                GROUP BY    d.cat_id 
                UNION
                SELECT      DISTINCT d.cat_id   AS prod
                        ,   p.id
                        ,   p.nome              AS id_prod
                        ,   SUM(0)              AS qtd_prod
                        ,   SUM(0)              AS total_prod
                        ,   SUM(d.qtd)          AS qtd_estoque
                FROM        lc_controle c 
                INNER JOIN  lc_detalhe  d ON d.controle_id  = c.id 
                INNER JOIN  lc_cat      p ON p.id           = d.cat_id 
                WHERE       d.tipo      = '0' 
                        AND c.dtConcat  < '$dtinicial' 
                        AND c.exportado = 'Sim' 
                GROUP BY    d.cat_id
            ) TMP
ORDER BY    TMP.qtd_prod DESC
```

Em princípio o `DISTINCT` estará a mais no `SELECT` principal, visto que o `UNION` valida duplicados, mas de qualquer forma, mal não faz!

---

**Edit**

Coloquei o `SUM` também nas colunas que estão com valor "0", caso contrário iria provocar problemas na consulta porque são valores numéricos e não estão agrupados.

Comment: João, obrigado pela ajuda...mas a segunda parte ele não está somando as quantidades e está trazendo todos os itens e não apenas os itens que tem movimento da primeira parte...to mexendo aqui mas não consegui resolver...

Comment: O _SUM_ não está a ser feito no 2º _SELECT_? Estranho... se executar cada consulta individualmente, que resultados tem?

Comment: Se rodo apenas a primeira parte o resultado é o mesmo com a segunda, o problema está na segunda parte, somei manualmente as qtd da primeira parte e está trazendo as quantidades corretas...tenho um item que ele mostra na primeira parte e tive saída no período informado de 426 unidades e entrada até a data inicial que fica na segunda parte de 600 unidades e ele mostra zero

Comment: Atenção que na 2ª consulta ele vai somar **apenas** as quantidades anteriores à data inicial! Não sei se está a ter isso em conta.

Comment: sim é isso mesmo que preciso, esse item que te falei a entrada dele foi antes da data inicial por isso ele deveria ter somado

Comment: Tem a certeza que o _SELECT_ que colocou na sua questão devolvia dados? Usando os _INNER JOIN_ a tabela _lc_controle_ tem que ter obrigatoriamente registos na _lc_detalhe_ e essa na _lc_cat_. Confirme pf a informação

Comment: Devolvia sim as informações só que separadas, tinha uma consulta para entradas e outras para saidas, preciso unificar justamente para ter as 2 informações no mesmo relatorio, sendo assim: o usuario escolhe a data inicial e data final para consulta o relatorio traz todos os itens que tiveram movimentação nesse periodo da seguinte maneira: Nome do produto quantidade vendida quantidade entrada e valor total da venda

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81063/discussion-between-joao-martins-and-robert).

Answer (score 1):

Voce vai ter que usar um Union Select, e para isso os dois select tem que ter a mesma quantidade e os mesmos nomes de campos de retorno;

```
 Select prod, id_prod, qtd_prod, total_prod from ((
      SELECT DISTINCT d.cat_id prod, p.id, p.nome id_prod, 
      SUM( d.qtd ) AS qtd_prod, SUM( d.valor_total ) AS total_prod 
      FROM lc_controle c 
      INNER JOIN lc_detalhe d ON d.controle_id = c.id 
      INNER JOIN `lc_cat` p ON p.id = d.cat_id 
      WHERE d.tipo = '0'
    ) as t1 
    union select (
      SELECT DISTINCT d.cat_id prod, p.id, p.nome id_prod, 
      SUM( d.qtd ) AS qtd_estoque, 0 as total_prod 
      FROM lc_controle c 
      INNER JOIN lc_detalhe d ON d.controle_id = c.id 
      INNER JOIN `lc_cat` p ON p.id = d.cat_id 
      WHERE d.tipo = '0' 
      and c.dtConcat < '$dtinicial' 
      and c.exportado = 'Sim' 
      GROUP BY d.cat_id 
      ORDER BY qtd_estoque DESC
    ) as t2
) as t3
```

referencia : [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html)

Comment: fiz as pressas aqui, mas adaptando as suas necessidades deve resolver.

Comment: deu erro, pq vc tirou a data inicial e final no BETWEEN, não sei muito de select......#1064 - Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a 'union select (
      SELECT DISTINCT d.cat_id prod, p.id, p.nome id_prod, 
   ' na linha 9